# ¿Cómo guardo una imagen en SQL Server para mostrarla en un DataGridView?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagrid

Alguien sabe como guardo una imagen, se que debe ser declarada como "image" pero yo la declare como de tipo "String" para que la pase como cadena y quiero guardarla después de a verla seleccionado para que cuando se haga una consulta se muestren los datos y la imagen, gracias a los interesados.

Antes que todo, gracias por interesarse en mi caso significa mucho. Al lado del campo imagen podemos observar dos botones el primero me permite cargar la imagen y el segundo la guarda.

Mi pregunta va dirigida al segundo boton, quiero guardarla para después mostrarla con los datos, ojala se entienda este punto, estoy abierto a sus consejos y comentarios, buen dia a todos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Joey, bienvenido a SOes. Sería bueno que puedas [edit] tu pregunta y que incluyas el código que estas usando para intentar alcanzar tu objetivo, y  tambien que indiques en que parte esta el error que estas experimentando. Puedes ver el siguiente enlace para saber como mejorar tu pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Saludos!

Comment: si declaras el campo como string quiere decir que estas persistiendo solo el nombre del archivo, pero la imagen fisicamente esta en una carpeta del disco, no? o guardas la imagen serializada a base64

Answer (score 1):

No se si lo que queres guardar es una imagen en la base de datos, o el directorio de la imagen. Asumiendo que es la imagen

En SQL Server deberías crear la tabla de la siguiente manera

```
CREATE TABLE Ejemplo
(
    id int identity(1,1) ,
    imagen image NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Ejemplo PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id) 
)
```

En la aplicacion .Net para cargar la imagen en un pictureBox y guardarla en una variable

```
private void browseButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Se crea el OpenFileDialog
    OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    // Se muestra al usuario esperando una acción
    DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();

    // Si seleccionó un archivo (asumiendo que es una imagen lo que seleccionó)
    // la mostramos en el PictureBox de la inferfaz
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(dialog.FileName);
    }
}
```

Para guardar la imagen en la base de datos

```
private void guardarButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       // Objetos de conexión y comando
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=
(local);Initial Catalog=store;Integrated Security=SSPI");
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();

       // Estableciento propiedades
       cmd.Connection = conn;
       cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Ejemplo VALUES (@image)";

      // Creando los parámetros necesarios
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", System.Data.SqlDbType.Image);

       // Asignando el valor de la imagen

       // Stream usado como buffer
       System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
       // Se guarda la imagen en el buffer
       pictureBox.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
       // Se extraen los bytes del buffer para asignarlos como valor para el 
       // parámetro.
       cmd.Parameters["@image"].Value = ms.GetBuffer();

       conn.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       conn.Close();
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Te dejo algunos links de referencia
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb972266.aspx
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeaXs8kGNeY

Saludos

Comment: Es interesante tu respuesta, lo voy a intentar, en verdad gracias Alejandro